# How to initialize CADisplayLink with target on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos

[CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink) is available for the following platforms:

- iOS
- iPadOS
- macOS
- Mac Catalyst
- tvOS
- visionOS

But [CADisplayLink.init(target:selector:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink/1621228-init) is not available for `macOS`. What's the proper way to achieve the same behavior for this platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a `CADisplayLink` from an `NSView`, `NSScreen`, `NSWindow` using their respective [`displayLink(target:selector:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/4191632-displaylink) method.

```
let displayLink = someView.displayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(someAction))
```

Though this is not mentioned in the documentation, the [AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/appkit-release-notes-for-macos-14#Display-Link) mention:

> The `CADisplayLink` will automatically track the display the view is on, and will be automatically suspended if it isn’t on a display.